# ScrollView adds large space at the bottom

Tags: android, android-scrollview

My main Activity has a number of buttons, that fit below each other on a large Tablet screen, but not on a smaller Phone screen. I added a ScrollView, so that the user can scroll down to the other buttons if the screen size requires it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/bg"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackSelectorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"                
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button                    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="foo" />
        <!-- More buttons -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This kinda works, however I have a large blank space below the last button (i.e. the ScrollView can scroll down too far). Both on an actual Tablet and on the emulator with a Phone configuration. If I `center` the inner LinearLayout (instead of `center_horizontal`), the space is evenly spread between the top and the bottom, which I don't want neither. How do I fix this layout?

I hope this image makes it more clear, imagine that the ScrollView has been completely scrolled down and showing the last buttons. The blank space I mean is the one below *Button 6* on the right image:

[image]

Comment: Can you draw what you want?

Comment: Done, I hope this makes it easier to visualize.

Comment: try giving the `ScrollView` `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. I doubt the space is inside the scrollview but actually below

Comment: Yes it does Lenart, wrap the ScrollView around a vertical LinearLayout, put `maxWeightSum=3`, and give each button a `weigth=1`. Done :) LinearLayout should fill_parent, scroll layout should define the viewport size of the linear layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, it wasn't really related to the layout (unless I'm missing something). I tried commenting out the background attributed, and it suddenly worked. The background imaged (`@drawable/bg`) was simply too big and caused the scrolling. I converted the background into a 9-patch image, so it could be scaled automatically, and voilà, the additional space was gone.
Still, if this would've been achievable without 9-patch, I'd still be interested to hear if this can be done in the XML file.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding this attribute to your ScrollView element.
android:fillViewport="true"

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" > ... </ScrollVIew>
```

Ref: [ScrollView Ref](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent" should be changed to android:layout_height="0dp"

Answer (score 1):

you can use this attribute in scrollview to avoid extra padding at bottom of view

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with my code..Work perfectly:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/bg"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trackSelectorText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"                
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button                    
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="foo" />
    <!-- More buttons -->
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

May be Help you.......!!